# muliple monitor software for Mac

Tags: macos, mac, multiple-monitors

I have 2 monitor for my Mac that's running OS X. I'm looking for software that will fit the currently active window to monitor 1 by pressing (for example) <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> or fit it to monitor 2 by pressing (for example) <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>.

I'd also like to have a menu bar on both screens. Ideally the software should be free.

Comment: Probably not exactly what you want, but still: http://superuser.com/questions/162849/tiling-window-manager-for-mac-os-x

Comment: And - this one should have been migrated long time ago - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273242/is-there-anything-like-winsplit-revolution-for-mac-os-x#275336

Comment: Two menu bars will likely not be possible. I remember a tool that gave the menubar contents as context menu when pressing a hot key, that might be an option for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Divvy](http://mizage.com/divvy/) will allow you to resize an application by pressing a hotkey. You can assign different hotkeys to different window sizes.

[SecondBar](http://blog.boastr.net/?page_id=79) will put a menu bar on your second monitor.

Answer (score 0):

#### [SizeUp](http://irradiatedsoftware.com/sizeup/)

[image: sizeup]

Separate actions for moving a window to another display and maximizing it.

#### [Divvy](http://mizage.com/divvy/)

[image: divvy]

#### [Breeze](http://www.autumnapps.com/breeze/)

[image: breeze]

I haven't tested the window states with multiple displays though.

---

#### [SecondBar](http://blog.boastr.net/?page_id=79)

[image: secondbar]

#### [MenuEverywhere](http://www.binarybakery.com/menueverywhere.html)

[image: menueverywhere]

#### [MenuPop](http://www.binarybakery.com/menupop.html)

[image: menupop]